# PHP parameter passing

Tags: php

im new to php and having some trouble with parameter passing in functions. I can't get my function to execute properly. This is the function.

```
     function validateUser($username){

          if(!empty($_POST)) 
          { 

              if(strlen($_POST['username']) < 5) 
              { 

                 die("Please enter a valid username"); 

              } 
}
```

thanks

Comment: your function need one more bracket `}` maybe. Or, what did you get exactly ??

Comment: You can see what comes to your script in the `$_POST` variable by executing `echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); echo "</pre>";`

Comment: Your code is a bit strange because you pass user name to function in parameter named `$username` but inside of the function you don't use this parameter and validate what you have in `$_POST['username']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter of the function is what you pass to the function when you call it. You then access it within your function like any other variable.

```
function validateUser($username){
    if(strlen($username) < 5) 
    { 
        die("Please enter a valid username"); 
    } 
}
```

You then would call it using the value you want to validate like this:

```
validateUser($_POST['username']);
```

Tip:  Don't use `die()` in your functions. Have them return `true` or `false` and then have the code that calls it decide how to handle the error.

Answer (score 1):

The parameters ain't passed in a POST variable. The way you formed your parameters when defining the function is the way you use them.

```
function validateUser($username)
{
    if(strlen($username) < 5) 
    { 
        return 0;
    } 
}
```